# Merging large data in Python in local machine

Tags: python, merge, large-data

I have 140 csv files. Each file has 3 variables and is about 750 GB. Number of observation varies from 60 to 90 million.

I also have another small file, *treatment_data* - with 138000 row (for each unique ID) and 21 column (01 column for `ID` and 20 columns of 1s and 0s indicating whether the ID was given a particular treatment or not.

The variables are,

- `ID_FROM`: A Numeric ID
- `ID_TO`: A Numeric ID
- `DISTANCE`: A numeric variable of physical distance between `ID_FROM` and `ID_TO`

(So in total, I have 138000*138000 (= 19+ Billion)rows - for every possible bi-lateral combination all ID, divided across these 140 files.

**Research Question:** Given a distance, how many neighbors (of each treatment type) an `ID` has.

So I need help with a system (preferably in Pandas) where

- the researcher will input a *distance*
- the program will look over all the files and filter out the the
  rows wither `DISTANCE` between `ID_FROM` and `ID_TO` is less than
  the given *distance*
- output a single dataframe. (`DISTANCE` can be dropped at this
  point)
- merge the dataframe with the *treatment_data* by matching `ID_TO` 
  with `ID`. (`ID_TO` can be dropped at this point)
- collapse the data by `ID_FROM` (group_by and sum the 1s, across
  20 treatment variable.

(In the Final output dataset, I will have 138000 row and 21 column. 01 column for `ID`. 20 column for each different treatment type. So, for example,  I will be able to answer the question, "Within '2000' meter, How many neighbors of '500' (ID) is in 'treatment_media' category?"

IMPORTANT SIDE NOTE:

- The `DISTANCE` variable range between 0 to roughly the radius of an
  average sized US State (in meter). Researcher is mostly interested to
  see what happens with in 5000 meter. Which usually drops 98% of
  observations. But sometimes, he/she will check for longer distance
  measure too. So I have to keep all the observations available.
  Otherwise, I could have simply filtered out the `DISTANCE` more than
  5000 from the raw input files and made my life easier. The reason I
  think this is important is that, the data are sorted based in
  `ID_FROM` across 140 files. If I could somehow rearrange these 19+
  billion rows based on `DISTANCE` and associate them have some kind of
  dictionary system, then the program does not need to go over all the
  140 files. Most of the time, the researcher will be looking into only
  2 percentile of `DISTANCE` range. It seems like a colossal waste of
  time that I have to loop over 140 files. But this is a secondary
  thought. Please do provide answer even if you can't use this
  additional side-note.
- I tried looping over 140 files for a particular distance in Stata, It
  takes 11+ hour to complete the task. Which is not acceptable as the
  researcher will want to vary the distance with in 0 to 5000 range.
  But, most of the computation time is wasted on reading each dataset
  on memory (that is how Stata do it). That is why I am seeking help in
  Python.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a particular reason that you need to do the whole thing in Python?
 This seems like something that a SQL database would be very good at. I think a basic outline like the following could work:

```
TABLE Distances {
  Integer PrimaryKey,
  String IdFrom,
  String IdTo,
  Integer Distance
}

INDEX ON Distances(IdFrom, Distance);

TABLE TreatmentData {
  Integer PrimaryKey,
  String Id,
  String TreatmentType
}

INDEX ON TreatmentData(Id, TreatmentType);

-- How many neighbors of ID 500 are within 2000 meters and have gotten
-- the "treatment_media" treatment?
SELECT
  d.IdFrom AS Id,
  td.Treatment,
  COUNT(*) AS Total
FROM Distances d
JOIN TreatmentData td ON d.IdTo = td.Id
WHERE d.IdFrom = "500"
  AND d.Distance <= 2000
  AND td.TreatmentType = "treatment_media"
GROUP BY 1, 2;
```

There's probably some other combination of indexes that would give better performance, but this seems like it would at least answer your example question.

Comment: I am not familiar with SQL. I will look into it.